# Dataset fails on StringMatchQ warning due to Missing value

Tags: string-manipulation, dataset, missing

Missing values are a pain mathematically and computationally in general not just in WL, but I think this problem is more related to `Dataset` handling of warnings:

`Select` Works w/ a warning on Association lists::

```
{<|"a" -> "hey"|>, <| "a" -> Missing[]|>} // 
 Select[StringMatchQ[#a, "hey"] &]
```

> ```
> StringMatchQ::strse: "String or list of strings expected at position 1 in \!\(StringMatchQ[Missing[], \"hey\"]\). "
> {<|"a" -> "hey"|>}
> ```

Fails as a `Query`:

```
Dataset[{<|"a" -> "hey"|>, <| "a" -> Missing[]|>} ] [
 Select[StringMatchQ[#a, "hey"] &]]
```

> Missing["Failed"]

The `Dataset` docs only mentions `Missing` 4x and not in this context. Is there a workaround that lets it ignore such warnings?

Comment: One workaround for above is pre-replace missing values by empty string or similar, `Query[All, {"a" -> Replace[Missing[] -> ""]}]`, violates the spirit of `Missing`

Comment: `Select[StringMatchQ[ToString[#a], "hey"] &]`?

Comment: Why not just keep it Quiet. 
Dataset[{<|"a" -> "hey"|>, <|"a" -> Missing[]|>}][
 Select[Function[Quiet[StringMatchQ[#a, "hey"]]]]]

Comment: As If[] anyone is listening: Dataset[{<|"a" -> "hey"|>, <|"a" -> Missing[]|>, <|"a" -> 23|>}][
 Select[Function[If[Head[#a] == String , StringMatchQ[#a, "hey"]]]]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example you give, your Query function asks if the value at element "a" is a string match for "hey". This generates the message because the value for a is not a string in the second row of your dataset.

For this particular case, one solution would be to require an exact match:

```
data = Dataset[{<|"a" -> "hey"|>, <|"a" -> Missing[]|>}];
Normal@data[Select[#a === "hey"&]]
```

> ```
> {<|"a"->"hey"}|>
> ```

This works just fine in the example, but if you need to use an actual string match, e.g. of a string pattern, rather than a match using SameQ (===), I don't see a method that's particularly more elegant than changing your select function:

```
data[Select[StringQ[#a] && StringMatchQ[#a, "hey"] &]]
```

That said, as chuy noted in your question's comments, you can also force the #a to be a string:

```
data[Select[StringMatchQ[ToString[#a], "hey"] &]]
```

Or, as alancalvitti noted, you can pre-select the valid rows:

```
data[All, {"a" -> Replace[_Missing -> ""]}][Select[#a == "hey" &]]
```

Or, as Hans points out, you can use a Quiet[] form:

```
data[Select[Quiet[StringMatchQ[#a "hey"]] &]]
```

All of these produce correct results.

Comment: This problem shows up generically w/ `Missing`, it's inconvenient to modify the logic just to handle those.

Comment: In that case you might consider something like this:
`Block[{Missing}, Missing[___]:=""; data[Select[#a == "hey"&]]];`
The block + `Missing[___] := "";` will redefine all of the instances of Missing[...] (with any number of arguments) in your dataset while it evaluates it. Note that it will affect all missing entries, not just the ones you intend to be strings.

Comment: Thanks butr even wrapping `Block` is a pain - the behavior should be specified globally. Also, ran into an edge case where `data // Select[Quiet...]` works but `data[Select[Quiet...]]`fails.