# A Query using Select and Quiet fails but Select by itself works

Tags: dataset, query, missing

This is closely related to the question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/dataset-fails-on-stringmatchq-warning-due-to-missing-value/), the key difference is that here data is structured as nested `Association` rather than a flat list:

```
data2 = <|"1" -> <|"a" -> "hey now"|>, "2" -> <|"a" -> Missing[]|>|> // 
  Dataset;
```

[image]

```
data2  // Select[Quiet @StringMatchQ[#a, "hey*"] &] // Normal
```

> `<|"1" -> <|"a" -> "hey now"|>|>`

Note, this will fail without the use of `Quiet` to suppress a `Failure` due to the match on `Missing`. And fails anyway as a `Query`:

```
data2[ Select[Quiet [StringMatchQ[#a, "hey*"] &]]]
```

> `Missing["Failed"]`

The typical workaround: `data2 // Normal // Dataset` does not help here.

Comment: Isn't the issue entirely that you want StringMatchQ to work with non-Strings?

Comment: You can use either `data2[Select[StringMatchQ[ToString@#a, "hey*"] &]]` or the wordier `data2[Select[
  Length[Cases[{#a}, x_String /; StringMatchQ[x, "hey*"] ]] > 0 &]]` if you feel the need to avoid `ToString`

Comment: As intented, `StringMatchQ`  does not match `Missing[]` values, and its warning is suppressed by `Quiet` though somehow not as a `Query`.

Comment: @alancalvitti The last comment I left in your previous post should help data2[
 Select[Function[If[Head[#a] == String, StringMatchQ[#a, "hey*"]]]]]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest "workaround" I've found to prevent your query from aborting is to set properly the `Query` option [**`FailureAction`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FailureAction.html) which is indeed by default set to **`"Abort"`** ! ;)

Given your data  :

```
myDataset = <|"1" -> <|"a" -> "hey now"|>, "2" -> <|"a" -> Missing[]|>|> // Dataset;
myQuery = Select[StringMatchQ[#a, "hey*"] &];
```

the **default behavior** is to simply **abort** with a Failure message:

```
myDataset[myQuery]
```

> [image]

**unless you set :**

```
myDataset[myQuery, FailureAction -> None]
```

> [image]

The query did not abort, the result is correct but a warning message was printed. To suppress the message you can as before simply wrap the command in `Quiet`.

### Remarks

1/ Regarding this `FailureAction` option, I thought first that the solution would be to set it rather to `"Drop"` but the query returns ``` Dataset``$DropPlaceholder ``` ... Not sure what happens here ...

2/ There is also another very interesting query option: [**`MissingBehavior`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MissingBehavior.html) which I thought was even more suited here. Not sure again why it does not work either.

3/ Why (as OP asked) does `Select[Quiet@StringMatchQ[#a, "hey*"] &][myDataset]` return the correct result without Failure, whereas `myDataset[Select[Quiet@StringMatchQ[#a, "hey*"] &]]` abort ?? It seems that this second form is actually working in version 10.0 according to @Hans answer ? Anyone to confirm ?
(At the time of this answer I'm using v10.2.)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help

```
data2[ Select[Function[If[Head[#a] == String, StringMatchQ[#a, "hey*"]]]]]
```

Then can you try

```
    data2[
 Select[Function[Quiet[StringMatchQ[#a, "hey*"]]]]]

$Version
10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)
```

Returned same as the If[]

Or re-written as

```
    data2[
 Select[(Quiet[StringMatchQ[#a, "hey*"]]) &]]
```

Note the placement of ().

Comment: No, the focus of this q is on `Query`'s behavior with respect to `Quiet`